# Getting javascript var from .json return

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have a simple API setup that I need to pull some basic information from. Truly, there are two variables that I am storing on heroku:

```
{ "mylong":"38.804858" , "mylatt":"-77.045120" }
```

My goal is to bring these two objects into a javascript variable and use them. Here is what I have thus far in my javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mylongMylatt;
      $.getJSON("http://someURLtoheroku.com/info.json", function(json){
        mylongMylatt=json;
      }
    var mylong = mylongMylatt.mylong[0]
    var mylatt = -mylongMylatt.mylatt[0]
```

This is a learning game for me so I would love to learn how to do this, not just the answer but am truly lost, thanks!

Comment: `$.getJSON` is *asynchronous*!  You can only access its data from *inside* the callback.

Comment: `[0]` is for accessing array elements. There's no array in the JSON, why are you doing that?

Comment: Barmar - just learning and this was _EXTREMELY_ helpful. Honestly, this whole side of development is new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using [getJSON documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

---

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mylongMylatt;
        $.getJSON("http://someURLtoheroku.com/info.json", {
            format: "json"
        }).done(function( data ) {
            //.done subscribes to the .ajax promise and will execute on success.
            //json here is actually an object
            var mylong=data.mylong;
            var mylatt=data.mylatt;
        });
    });
```

***Note:** The Promise interface in jQuery 1.5 also allows jQuery's Ajax methods, including `$.getJSON()`, to chain multiple `.done()`, `.always()`, and `.fail()` callbacks on a single request, and even to assign these callbacks after the request may have completed. If the request is already complete, the callback is fired immediately.*

*Since it is a `.ajax` is a promise it accepts the `deferred.object` http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/*

---

### The following also should work without using `.promise`

***Description:** This works because the `$.getJSON` function second parameter is the first success function.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mylongMylatt;
        $.getJSON("http://someURLtoheroku.com/info.json", function(json){
            var mylong = json.mylong;
            var mylatt = -json.mylatt;
        }
```

Comment: This worked really well, thank you for your help! The .done situation, can you explain that please?

Comment: @user1623976 updated answer to explain, let me know if you understand the added information.  ASync is where this all comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the JSON properties through a `.`

```
$.getJSON("http://someURLtoheroku.com/info.json", function(json){
   var myLong = json.mylong
   var mylatt = json.mylatt;
 });
```

However, you can't access those variables until *after* the `getJSON` call has completed, due to the async nature of the call, so you'll need to do whatever work you want inside the callback.